# Unable to type anything on Chromium

Tags: lubuntu, chromium

I have the latest 14.4 Lubuntu (Spanish) version already updated. I have found the same bug in two machines. The machines are a 11 year old P4 2.5Ghz, Geforce mx 420 and a 9 year old Dell laptop Pentium Cetrino 1.7 Ghz.

I can focus the cursor on any dialog appearing in Chromium: URL bar, gmail dialogs, composing messages in gmail etc, but I am not able to type anything on them. When I type nothing happens. Is this a known bug in the latest Chromium version? Anything else is correct. I can browse normally and websites are rendered correctly.

I have tried to resinstall Chromium in the two machines and I have deleted the Chromium profile dir but I still unable to type anything, even with a new profile. Firefox runs flawlessly and any other things in the PCs are Ok.

Comment: hey there and thanks for the effort,
any other suggestions, update to avoid turning off ibus, it is indeed still not a good fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Preferences > Language Support and change `Keyboard input method system` from `ibus` to `none`. Then log out and log in again.

Comment: Great! Chromium is working fine now. Thanks for the trick!

Comment: In Chromium, I have "Settings > Languages" (after first enabling "Show Advanced Settings...." at the bottom).  In "Languages", button to modify "Language and input settings...", but nothing about ibus specifically.  So I think you mean at the system level to disable ibus.  But this isn't acceptable as I need ibus for keying in other applications.

Comment: @rik.shaw please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/472224/downside-to-disabling-ibus ... Unfortunately, there's hasn't been any answer.

Comment: Also see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360388

Comment: @DKBose, I think the reason no one is answering the other question is because it is *up to you* if you need ibus or not :).  In my work, we use custom ibus keyboads to key in minority languages.  Obviously if I turn off ibus, I can't use those custom keyboards.  If you aren't using custom keyboards, then it is fine to turn off ibus :)

Comment: For any of you who were as confused as I was about this answer ...
This is NOT referencing preferences within Chromium.
It IS referencing preferences within Ubuntu.
I spent 20 minutes trying to find that in the Chromium settings.