# Downside to disabling IBus?

Tags: google-chrome, ibus

To edit documents on my Google Drive accessed via Google Chrome 35.0.1916.114 on Lubuntu 14.04, I find I need to use

```
ibus exit
```

Only then can I enter anything. This is a known bug: [chromium 34 from proposed does not take input from keyboard in first entry point on several webpages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1307648) possibly because of the change to Aura.

But my question is whether I can put something like `ibus exit` in my autostart file safely. In other words, will I break something else? I've looked at `man ibus` and at https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/ReadMe but couldn't clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

IBus is used for typing non-Latin characters for languages like Chinese, Japanese, or Korean. If you don't need to type characters in these languages, you should be ok without running IBus.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are you really using IBus?

IBus is not used by default, user need set it up to use it.

```
$ env | grep -i -e im= -e im_
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=
XMODIFIERS=@im=none
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim

$ pgrep -a ibus
```

If you can't find in both commands then you are not using IBus. IBus does support many languages, but it is there to cover missing support of [CJK ( Chinese, Japanese, and Korean languages)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) input which is missing in [XIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Input_Method).

You can explicitly set XIM as input method:

- Control center → Language support → Language tab → Keyboard input method system: XIM.
- `qtconfig-qt4` → Interface tab → Default input method: XIM.