# Typing freezes in Chromium omnibox and enigmatic letter "a" in bar since Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, freeze, chromium

Since Lubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04 I can't use Chromium browser, because serious typing freezes appears in Chromium omnibox. It is possible type site address only in first tab, only one time after Chromium restart. After this it is impossible to change anything in Chromium omnibox by keyboard. It looks like keyboard not working completely. I used Chromium few years from Ubuntu 10.10 till 13.10 without problems. Typing freezes appears from 14.04 in both Lubuntu and Ubuntu.

Another note. Blue letter "a" appears in bar:

[image]

Exactly simultaneously with described problem. The letter is not a problem, but may it linked with typing freezes in some way. Clicking on the blue letter "a" don't give any effect.

How to solve problem with typing freezes in Chromium? Thanks.

Comment: The blue "a" means that you are on the Aura toolkit. This "a" will disappear in Chromium 36.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved here: [Unable to type anything on Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457541/unable-to-type-anything-on-chromium?rq=1) by DK Bose:

Go to Preferences > Language Support and change Keyboard input method system from **ibus** to **none**. Then log out and log in again.

After changing **ibus** to **none** in Keyboard input methods Chromium works great.